# Send X12 AS2 Document with BizTalk 2013

Tags: biztalk, edi, x12

I asked a question about EDI before [EDI X12 Implementation with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724006/edi-x12-implementation-with-c-sharp)

And i'm need help again. We have decided to use BizTalk 2013, i was able to install BizTalk 2013, i need some assistance.

Our partner sent a document about AS2 Trading Partner Setup and some certificates for both production and test enviroment. The information in this document is:

- AS2 Identifier and URL
- MDN: SHA1
- Encryption Algorithm: Triple DES
- MDN Delivery Type (Synchronous/Asynchronous):
- Synchronous  (Asynchronous also supported)
- Request Signed Receipt: Yes
- Software: Cyclone Interchange
- Payload Security Type (e.g., Signed, SignedAndEncrypted, etc.): SignedAndEncrypted

I read the tutorial below and try to integrate to our solution
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727687(v=bts.80).aspx

Steps i did;

- Create Visual Studio Project that contains X12 850 document schema and deploy it.
- Created one way receive port to receive edi document we create.
- Install the certificate to Local computer > Other people
- Created static solicit-response send port to send edi document to our partner and select the certificate for encrypt message.
- Created parties for us and for our partner.
- Created agreement between us and our partner. Select AS2 for protocol.

  I did following changes in "Us > Our Partner" tab.

  - In Acknowledgements(MDNs) page, i selected Process inbound MDN into MessageBox for routing/delivery options and Request MDN boxes.
  - In Validation page i selected Message should be encrypted and DES3.
  - In Send Ports i selected port that i created.

Now when i copy file to receive port i created, BizTalk gives an error like this:

`The AS2 Decoder encountered an exception during processing.  Details of the message and exception are as follows:  AS2-From:"" AS2-To:"" MessageID:"" MessageType: "unknown" Exception:"An AS2 message was received that did not contain the AS2-From header."`

My test EDI document looks like (I tried with header information, and without header, results are same)

```
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
AS2-From: ZZUS
AS2-To: ZZTHEM
AS2-Version: 1.0
Message-ID: AS2Message-001

ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*US      *ZZ*THEM                    
*130530*1244*U*00401*00001234*0*P*:
GS*PO*US*THEM*20130530*1244*1234*X*004010
ST*850*1234
BEG*00*SA*PO1234**20130530**ZZ
ITD*ZZ***20080101*0**0*******1
DTM*002*20130615
N1*ST*US*92*1426136
N3*6719 THEALL RD STE B
N4*HOUSTON*TX*77066-1215*US
PER*ZZ*No Contact specified
PO1*1*1*CA***VN*MSC097030
PID*F****HAND SANITIZER,EPI-CLENZ,4 OZ,70% ETHYL
CTT*1
SE*44*1234
GE*1*1234
IEA*1*00001234
```

Btw, i'm creating document by C# code, is there any easy way BizTalk provides to create/read X12 documents like this?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With any EDI application worth its salt (and I wouldn't put BizTalk in that category), you should be able to create a map.  With all the abstraction layers that BizTalk uses, you should be able to use the various "adapters", including the EDI adapter to create a "map".  The map should allow you to transform your source to a target, and then connect to another adapter to control workflow and delivery.

Here is a link to an example workflow for you:  http://www.nullskull.com/a/1339/using-edi-adapter-to-sendreceive-po-within-trading-partners.aspx